# Calculate Probability of a threshold being reached based on past events.

Tags: probability

I'm trying to note a level of risk for a person falling sick too many times in a year.

They cross this threshold if they are sick for more than ten days of if they have more than 3 separate incidents.

Based on their past sickness record of the current year, is there a way to calculate the chance they are likely to cross this threshold before the end of the year?

Edit:
I have tried to plot this with excel and come up with a formula which might work for just the ten days absent. Not the 3 separate incidents.

S = Number of sick days they've had

T = Threshold of days allowed to be sick (10)

N = Number of days from start of the year til today

$$
(1-(1-S/N)^{365-N})^{T-S}
$$

Providing this works as intended the only issue I see is the probability for $S/N^{365-N}$ would decrease by $N+1$ for everyday of $T-S$ as there would be one day less day of the year for each accounted sick day, but I figure this number would be too smaller to really matter.

Edit: I'd love if someone knew if the above formula or it's rearrangement has a name.

Comment: You could start by defining random variables and modeling the process somehow. Perhaps the sick days can be modeled as a Bernoulli/Poisson process? (Just an idea)

Comment: Hi @MattiP. I've found something that works but wondered if you knew if it was based of anything? I found a solution just playing with excel so know if there's a common formula out there that is similar to this.

Comment: Question: Consider 
$$
X_i= \left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & ~\text{if person is sick on day}~i \\
0 & ~\text{if person is not sick on day}~i \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Would you consider the $X_i$'s as independent? That is, does $P(X_i)$ depend on $P(X_{i-1})$ etc. ? If they are independent, and also $P(X_i)$ doesn't depend on $i$, I would recommend that you read this:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_process